# Compare two arrays and append to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two sets of cards array(a) and array(b)
Think of array(a) as a master set, and array(b) the players cards.

I am looping through array(a) and then checking if exists in array(b). If it does not then I deleted from array(a). html binds to the whats left in array(1)  the code below works fine for this.

But now I realize array(b) may have duplicates example [cardID:1, cardID:2, cardID:3, cardID:3, cardID:4]

So I added a third array as I want to keep the duplicates as well, I push to a final array. But this code does not get the duplicates cardID3, not sure how to do this?

```
var i = 0;
var entry1;
    while (i < this.myCardsArray.length) {
       entry1 = this.myCardsArray[i];
          if (this.cardsArray.some(function(entry2) { return entry1.id === entry2.cardID; })) {
              // Found, progress to next
              this.finalCardsArray.push(this.myCardsArray[i]) //added this line to save results
               ++i;
          } else {
              // Not found, remove
              this.myCardsArray.splice(i, 1);
          }
      }
```

Comment: Is the property id or card id...why the difference

Comment: Okay so you want to keep myCards and dupes? So you want to remove only the first element that is not in the other array?

Comment: CardID is the id of cards in array(b), id in array(a)
To start with I wanted to simply remove all cards from array(a) that did not match the cardID in array(b). But array(b) can have duplicates, so I am making a 3rd array and want to insert the contents of array(a). I know splice array(a) is not longer needed. Hope I am making sense

Comment: I'm not clear enough on your set up and requirements to answer this without making some assumptions. Can you post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var master_A = [
  {
    cardID: 1,
    extra: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    cardID: 2,
    extra: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    cardID: 3,
    extra: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    cardID: 4,
    extra: 'stuff'
  }
]
```

given, that the master set has uniqueness on id-s -> I would create a new object, that maps them to their id-s

```
var master_map_A = {};
master_A.forEach(function(card) {
  master_map_A[card.cardID] = card
})
```

And then reference them from the slave_B set, for whatever extra information would be necessary, by looping through the list and referencing as master_map_A[card.cardID] ...

```
var slave_B = [
  {
    cardID: 1
  },
  {
    cardID: 2
  },
  {
    cardID: 3
  },
  {
    cardID: 3
  },
  {
    cardID: 4
  }
]
```